# Retrieving data from sql database using $http.get

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, angularjs, ajax

This is the continuation of my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40056429/testing-a-page-using-angularjss-routing).
I used AngularJS's routing to load different html files.
For student display, data is retrieved from sql database using $http.get.

I like to check my ajax.php is really working.
From the browser, when run `localhost/ajax.php`
Then can see the info as

```
        MySQL host info: 
    [{"0":"1","id":"1","1":"Mark","Name":"Mark","2":"Male","Gender":"Male","3":"London","City":"London"},
    {"0":"2","id":"2","1":"John","Name":"John","2":"Male","Gender":"Male","3":"Chenni","City":"Chenni"},
    {"0":"3","id":"3","1":"Hint","Name":"Hint","2":"Male","Gender":"Male","3":"Singapore","City":"Singapore"},
    {"0":"4","id":"4","1":"Sara","Name":"Sara","2":"Female","Gender":"Female","3":"Sydney","City":"Sydney"},
    {"0":"5","id":"5","1":"Tom","Name":"Tom","2":"Male","Gender":"Male","3":"New York","City":"New York"},
    {"0":"6","id":"6","1":"Pam","Name":"Pam","2":"Male","Gender":"Male","3":"Los Angeles","City":"Los Angeles"},

    {"0":"7","id":"7","1":"Catherine","Name":"Catherine","2":"Female","Gender":"Female","3":"Chicago","City":"Chicago"},
    {"0":"8","id":"8","1":"Mary","Name":"Mary","2":"Femal","Gender":"Femal","3":"Houston","City":"Houston"},

    {"0":"9","id":"9","1":"Mike","Name":"Mike","2":"Male","Gender":"Male","3":"Phoenix","City":"Phoenix"},
    {"0":"10","id":"10","1":"Rosie","Name":"Rosie","2":"Female","Gender":"Female","3":"Manchestor","City":"Manchestor"},
    {"0":"11","id":"11","1":"Lim","Name":"Lim","2":"Male","Gender":"Male","3":"Singapore","City":"Singapore"},
    {"0":"12","id":"12","1":"Tony","Name":"Tony","2":"Male","Gender":"Male","3":"Hong Kong","City":"Hong Kong"},
    {"0":"13","id":"13","1":"Royce","Name":"Royce","2":"Male","Gender":"Male","3":"London","City":"London"},
    {"0":"14","id":"14","1":"Hitler","Name":"Hitler","2":"Male","Gender":"Male","3":"Germany","City":"Germany"},
    {"0":"15","id":"15","1":"Tommy","Name":"Tommy","2":"Male","Gender":"Male","3":"New Jersy","City":"New Jersy"}]
```

It looks correct. 
My database has the following data.

```
id  Name    Gender  City
1   Mark    Male    London
2   John    Male    Chenni
3   Hint    Male    Singapore
4   Sara    Female  Sydney
5   Tom     Male    New York
6   Pam     Male    Los Angeles
7   Catherine   Female  Chicago
8   Mary    Femal   Houston
9   Mike    Male    Phoenix
10  Rosie   Female  Manchestor
11  Lim     Male    Singapore
12  Tony    Male    Hong Kong
13  Royce   Male    London
14  Hitler  Male    Germany
15  Tommy   Male    New Jersy
```

My queries are

How can I debug my ajax.php in other better alternative ways? I use Netbeans IDE.
I have problem with displaying data at Students link.
Names are not displayed. If ajax.php has no issue, where could have problem?

Thanks

EDIT:
I changed my code to

connect.php

```
<?php
    // db credentials
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    define('DB_USER','root');
    define('DB_PASS','nyan');
    define('DB_NAME','Students');

    // Connect with the database.
    function connect()
    {
      $connect = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST ,DB_USER ,DB_PASS ,DB_NAME);

      if (mysqli_connect_errno($connect))
      {
        die("Failed to connect:" . mysqli_connect_error());
      }

      mysqli_set_charset($connect, "utf8");


      return $connect;
    }


?>
```

Ajax.php

```
<?php
    require 'connect.php';

    $connect = connect();

    // Get the data
    $students = array();
    $sql = "SELECT id, Name, Gender, City  FROM tblStudents";

    if($result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql))
    {
      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

      $cr = 0;
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
      {
          $students[$cr]['id']    = $row['id'];
          $students[$cr]['Name']  = $row['Name'];
          $students[$cr]['Gender'] = $row['Gender'];
          $students[$cr]['City'] = $row['City'];         
          $cr++;
      }
    }

    $json = json_encode($students);
    echo $json;
    exit;

?>
```

Script.js

```
var app = angular.module("Demo", ["ngRoute"])
                 .config(function($routeProvider){
                 $routeProvider
                 .when("/home", {
                     templateUrl:"Templates/home.html",
                     controller:"homeController"
                 })
                 .when("/courses", {
                     templateUrl:"Templates/courses.html",
                     controller:"coursesController"
                 })
                 .when("/students", {
                     templateUrl:"Templates/students.html",
                     controller:"studentsController"
                 })
            })
            .controller("homeController", function($scope){
                 $scope.message = "Home Page";
            })
            .controller("coursesController", function($scope){
                 $scope.courses = ["C#", "VB.NET", "SQL Server", "ASP.NET"];
            })
            .controller("studentsController", function ($scope, $http) {
                 $http.get("ajax.php") .then(function(response) {
                    $scope.students = response;
                 });

            });
```

It looks ok, but still have error at Chrome when I pressed F12

```
GET http://localhost:8383/favicon.ico net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

I tested as both Ajax.php and connect.php into /var/www/html folder and run localhost/Ajax.php
The returned data is correct and as follow.

```
[{"id":"1","Name":"Mark","Gender":"Male","City":"London"},{"id":"2","Name":"John","Gender":"Male","City":"Chenni"},{"id":"3","Name":"Hint","Gender":"Male","City":"Singapore"},{"id":"4","Name":"Sara","Gender":"Female","City":"Sydney"},{"id":"5","Name":"Tom","Gender":"Male","City":"New York"},{"id":"6","Name":"Pam","Gender":"Male","City":"Los Angeles"},{"id":"7","Name":"Catherine","Gender":"Female","City":"Chicago"},{"id":"8","Name":"Mary","Gender":"Femal","City":"Houston"},{"id":"9","Name":"Mike","Gender":"Male","City":"Phoenix"},{"id":"10","Name":"Rosie","Gender":"Female","City":"Manchestor"},{"id":"11","Name":"Lim","Gender":"Male","City":"Singapore"},{"id":"12","Name":"Tony","Gender":"Male","City":"Hong Kong"},{"id":"13","Name":"Royce","Gender":"Male","City":"London"},{"id":"14","Name":"Hitler","Gender":"Male","City":"Germany"},{"id":"15","Name":"Tommy","Gender":"Male","City":"New Jersy"}]
```

So Ajax.php and connect.php are working. Just AngularJs Script can't retrieve correctly. What is wrong in my Script.js?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40080518/angularjss-http-service-always-returns-error/40125911#40125911). Finally it worked with my persistent attack. Thanks all for your help and suggestions.