# AngularJS's http service always returns error

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, ajax

I am wondering why my AngularJS http service is always returning an error with status -1.

I have PHP code and run this as localhost/ajax.php. This file can retrieve data from the database. So php is working fine. The retrieved data is as follows:

```
[{"id":"1","Name":"Mark","Gender":"Male","City":"London"},  
{"id":"2","Name":"John","Gender":"Male","City":"Chenni"},
{"id":"3","Name":"Hint","Gender":"Male","City":"Singapore"},    
{"id":"4","Name":"Sara","Gender":"Female","City":"Sydney"},   
{"id":"5","Name":"Tom","Gender":"Male","City":"New York"},   
{"id":"6","Name":"Pam","Gender":"Male","City":"Los Angeles"},  
{"id":"7","Name":"Catherine","Gender":"Female","City":"Chicago"},  
{"id":"8","Name":"Mary","Gender":"Femal","City":"Houston"},  
{"id":"9","Name":"Mike","Gender":"Male","City":"Phoenix"},  
{"id":"10","Name":"Rosie","Gender":"Female","City":"Manchestor"},  
{"id":"11","Name":"Lim","Gender":"Male","City":"Singapore"},  
{"id":"12","Name":"Tony","Gender":"Male","City":"Hong Kong"},  
{"id":"13","Name":"Royce","Gender":"Male","City":"London"},  
{"id":"14","Name":"Hitler","Gender":"Male","City":"Germany"},  
{"id":"15","Name":"Tommy","Gender":"Male","City":"New Jersy"}]
```

This PHP file is called from my AngularJS http service, but that call returns always an error with status -1.

I looked at all the resources but got no clues.
My database is setup at localhost using Sql.

My queries are what could be the error. I think that those are making the http service return with error status -1.

My codes are is as follows:

Ajax.php

```
<?php
    require 'connect.php';

    $connect = connect();

    // Get the data
    $students = array();
    $sql = "SELECT id, Name, Gender, City  FROM tblStudents";

    if($result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql))
    {

      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
      $cr = 0;
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
      {
          $students[$cr]['id']    = $row['id'];
          $students[$cr]['Name']  = $row['Name'];
          $students[$cr]['Gender'] = $row['Gender'];
          $students[$cr]['City'] = $row['City'];         
          $cr++;          
      }
    }

    $json = json_encode($students);
    echo $json;
    exit;

?>
```

connect.php

```
<?php
    // db credentials
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    define('DB_USER','root');
    define('DB_PASS','nyan');
    define('DB_NAME','Students');

    // Connect with the database.
    function connect()
    {
      $connect = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST ,DB_USER ,DB_PASS ,DB_NAME);

      if (mysqli_connect_errno($connect))
      {
        die("Failed to connect:" . mysqli_connect_error());
      }

      mysqli_set_charset($connect, "utf8");


      return $connect;
    }


?>
```

Script.js

```
var app = angular.module("Demo", ["ngRoute"])
                 .config(function($routeProvider){
                 $routeProvider
                 .when("/home", {
                     templateUrl:"Templates/home.html",
                     controller:"homeController"
                 })
                 .when("/courses", {
                     templateUrl:"Templates/courses.html",
                     controller:"coursesController"
                 })
                 .when("/students", {
                     templateUrl:"Templates/students.html",
                     controller:"studentsController"
                 })
            })            
            .controller("homeController", function($scope){
                 $scope.message = "Home Page";
            })
            .controller("coursesController", function($scope){
                 $scope.courses = ["C#", "VB.NET", "SQL Server", "ASP.NET"];
            })
            .controller("studentsController", function ($scope, $http) {
                 $scope.students;
                 $http({                    
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'api/ajax.php'
                 }).then(function (response) {
                    $scope.students = response.data;
                 }, function (response) {  
                    console.log(response.data,response.status);
                 });                 
            });
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html ng-app="Demo">
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/Script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>        
    </head>
    <body >         
         <table style="font-family: Arial">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="header">
                    <h1>
                        WebSite Header
                    </h1>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-controller="studentsController">
                <td class="leftMenu">
                    <a href="#/home">Home</a>
                    <a href="#/courses">Courses</a>
                    <a href="#/students">Students</a>
                </td>
                <td class="mainContent">
                     <ng-view></ng-view>                    
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="footer">
                    <b>Website Footer</b>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to add header('Content-Type: application/json'); before you echo any json results in Ajax.php

Comment: @11mb what does it do? I don't see any difference.

Comment: It tells angular to expect result in json format. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script)  What do you mean by "My queries are what could be the error sources those are making the http service return with error"? Does your ajax call work when you echo a json string without query-ing the database in ajax.php?

Comment: try to make a call to blank Ajax.php and echo something from Ajax.php and see, weather u grtting any error,

Comment: @UmakantMane I run localhost/ajax.php and the response is as shown in the original post. They are data inside my database. So ajax.php is working.

Comment: @11mb Since it looks everything is fine for me, I can't figure out where the error source is. Where could have the error so that I can't retrieve data from database using http service?

Comment: @batuman It can be in all kind of places :) .. When you think the database is the problem, remove this code to test your proposition.

Comment: @11mb Since running localhost/ajax.php can retrieve data correctly, I consider ajax.php and connect.php are working as expected. Then AngularJS routing is working well also. I need to check Script.js's studentsController really call ajax.php and receive correct data. How can I debug?

Comment: I updated my answer.. You wrote that you test with localhost/ajax.php, but in your code i see: api/ajax.php. Maybe the URL is incorrect?

Comment: No,I copied ajax.php and connect.php manually to /var/www/html folder and tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, really finally, I could make it.
Following code makes the process works.

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>       
        <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/angular-route.js" type="text/javascript"></script>        
        <script src="Scripts/Script.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <link href="Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="Demo">
        <table style="font-family: Arial">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="header">
                    <h1>
                        WebSite Header
                    </h1>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="leftMenu">
                    <a href="#/home">Home</a>
                    <a href="#/courses">Courses</a>
                    <a href="#/students">Students</a>
                </td>
                <td class="mainContent">
                     <ng-view></ng-view>                    
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="footer">
                    <b>Website Footer</b>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

database.php

```
<?php

/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
    class Database{ 

        // specify your own database credentials 
        private $host = "localhost"; 
        private $db_name = "Students"; 
        private $username = "root"; 
        private $password = "nyan"; 
        public $conn; 

        // get the database connection 
        public function getConnection(){ $this->conn = null;

            try{
                $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
            }catch(PDOException $exception){
                echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
            }

            return $this->conn;
        }
    }
?>
```

Students.php

```
<?php

/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
    class Students{ 
        // database connection and table name 
        private $conn; 
        private $table_name = "tblStudents"; 

        // object properties 
        public $id; 
        public $name; 
        public $gender; 
        public $city; 

        // constructor with $db as database connection 
        public function __construct($db){ 
            $this->conn = $db;
        }
        // read products
        public function readAll(){

            // select all query
            $query = "SELECT 
                        id, name, gender, city 
                    FROM 
                        " . $this->table_name . "
                    ORDER BY 
                        id";

            // prepare query statement
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );

            // execute query
            $stmt->execute();

            return $stmt;
        }
    }

?>
```

ReadStudents.php

```
<?php

    // include database and object files  
    include_once 'database.php'; 
    include_once 'Students.php';

    // instantiate database and product object 
    $database = new Database(); 
    $db = $database->getConnection();

    // initialize object
    $students = new Students($db);

    // query products
    $stmt = $students->readAll();
    $num = $stmt->rowCount();

    $data="";

    // check if more than 0 record found
    if($num>0){

        $x=1;

        // retrieve our table contents
        // fetch() is faster than fetchAll()
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770630/pdofetchall-vs-pdofetch-in-a-loop
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            // extract row
            // this will make $row['name'] to
            // just $name only
            extract($row);

            $data .= '{';
                $data .= '"id":"'  . $id . '",';
                $data .= '"name":"' . $name . '",';
                $data .= '"gender":"' . $gender . '",';
                $data .= '"city":"' . $city . '"';
            $data .= '}'; 

            $data .= $x<$num ? ',' : ''; $x++; } 
    } 

    // json format output 
    echo '{"records":[' . $data . ']}'; 

?>
```

Script.js

```
var app = angular.module("Demo", ["ngRoute"])
                 .config(function($routeProvider){
                 $routeProvider
                 .when("/home", {
                     templateUrl:"Templates/home.html",
                     controller:"homeController"
                 })
                 .when("/courses", {
                     templateUrl:"Templates/courses.html",
                     controller:"coursesController"
                 })
                 .when("/students", {
                     templateUrl:"Templates/students.html",
                     controller:"studentsController"
                 })
            })

            .controller("homeController", function($scope){
                 $scope.message = "Home Page";
            })
            .controller("coursesController", function($scope){
                 $scope.courses = ["C#", "VB.NET", "SQL Server", "ASP.NET"];
            })
            .controller("studentsController", function ($scope, $http) {
                 $http.get("api/ReadStudents.php").success(function(response){
                    $scope.students = response.records;
                });                
            });
```

courses.html

```
<h1>Courses we offer</h1>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="course in courses">{{course}}</li>

</ul>
```

home.html

```
<h1>{{message}}</h1>
<div>
    PRAGIM established in 2000 by 3 s/w  engineers offers very cost effective training. 
</div>
<ul>
    <li>Training delivered by real time softwares experets</li>
    <li>Realtime project discussion relating to the possible interview questions</li>
    <li>Trainees can attend training and use lab untill you get a job</li>
    <li>Resume preparation and mockup interviews</li>
    <li>100% placement assistant</li>
    <li>lab facility</li>
</ul>
```

students.html

```
<h1>List of students</h1>
<ul >
    <li ng-repeat="student in students">{{student.name}}</li>    
</ul>
```

Comment: First of all .. I have no clue where your answer is to your problem, looking at you massive amount of code. Second: Your code from your question does not resemble the code of your answer. In your question you use mysqli in your answer you have suddenly switched to PDO (which by the way is a better choice) ?? .. SO please be specific about where your answer lies to your question and keep the post to a minimum in order to clearly understand what helped you solve your problem.

Comment: I made major changes in phps for database access. The rest of the codes are more or less similar. PDO and mysqli which is the better choice, not very sure. But I couldn't make it work using mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

You state in your question that your scripts probably breaks because of the database query.

When your query takes a long time it can cause a timeout. The response code -1 usually means the request was aborted, e.g. using a config.timeout according to the angular js documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http.

You can try to increase your timeout:

```
$http.get('ajax.php', {timeout: 5000, method: 'GET'});
```

In this example it will be set to 5 seconds.. Test your ajax.php to see how long your request takes.

Edit:

Also make sure you use the right URL. In your question you use a different URL to test your ajax call.

Comment: He can even use then method of angular, which will wait until response will come from server.

Comment: Thanks it doesn't work, even I extend to timeout : 10000.